# How to return all the users inside Meteor.users except for the current logged in user?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have a master user in my database that should be able to view all the users in the system.

Here is my code that return all the users in the collection.

```
Template.listEmployees.helpers({
    employees: function () {
            return Meteor.users.find({}, { sort: {createdAt: -1}});
        }
    });
```

Is it possible to return all the users except for the current logged in user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just exclude their `_id`:

```
Template.listEmployees.helpers({
  employees() {
    return Meteor.users.find({ _id: { $ne: Meteor.userId() }}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 }});
  }
});
```